# Which is the best book or tutorial or blog to start Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have planed to start using a framework in php development.  After going through several blogs on line and checking several questions here in stackoverflow I came to a conclusion to start with symfony 2.

I have recently learned php and created a demo application that works fine. now I realize I should go with a framework rather digging more with core php. I started reading [this book](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/index.html) but after finishing few chapters I found it a bit difficult and complex. I haven't used any framework before.

Can anyone please suggest me a book, tutorial, a blog or any other thing that I should start to make myself feel a bit more comfortable?

Comment: My source : http://www.netvibes.com/weba2lix#Symfony2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Symfony2 is young and documentation (with books and so on) is not as mature as Sf 1.4.

I think I've read somewhere that a book is in preparation.

Here is my sources of documentation :

- http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/index.html (you already know this one)
- http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/ (real life case, really usefull)
- http://storify.com/popofr13/symfony2#storify/p1 (Sf2 web ressources feed)
- http://miller.limethinking.co.uk/ (great articles)
- http://sftuts.com/doc/jobeet/en/index (Port from Jobeet tutorial of Sf 1.4, have been in work in progress for a while now)

Edit : You should keep on eye on twitter as well (tag "symfony2"), a lot is going on over there, each dev writing an article tweet about it.

Maybe others will share their sources.